# how can i search blank data for specific field in searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field, elastic-stack, is-empty, searchkick

```
class Sample
    field :title, type: String
    field :brand, type: String
end
```

```
i tried
    sample.search('*', {
    where: {
    title: {blank: ""}
    },
    page: 1, per_page:  50,
    order:  { _score: :desc, created_at: :desc },
    match: :word_middle, misspellings: false })
```

I Need to check empty titles in Sample model through searchkick

I searched on multiple elasticsearck github documentations

i refered this document https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying but not got any solution